# ModelState for EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using an editor template for a complex type (for example an employee). I do this because I want to edit several employees in one view. This works fine.
Now I need to add a validation error from the controller. But when I simply use

```
Modelstate.AddModelError
```

The error is added to my "outer" Model, not the model my editor template is working with. How can I pass through the error?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which property of your "outer model" (or view model) is concerned by this validation issue :

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Employee.FirstName", "FirstName is required");
```

This will target `MyOuterModel.Employee.FirstName`.

This works if you have one Employee object in your view model. If you work with a collection of employees, you can write `string.Format("Employee[{0}].FirstName", i)`.